# How to prove that a sum is a Riemmanian sum

Tags: riemann-integration, riemann-sum, chebyshev-polynomials, quadrature

Lets say that we have the well known Gauss-Chebyshev Quadrature rule of the first kind i.e,

$\int^1_{-1}f(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx= \sum^n_{k=1} w_kf(x_k) +R_n(f) $, where the nodes $x_k$ are $x_k=\cos(\frac{2k-1}{2n})$, and the weights are all equal $w_k=\frac{\pi}{n}, \quad k=1,2,...,n$

and we want to show that the quadrature sum $Q_n(f)=\sum^n_{k=1} w_kf(x_k)$ is a Riemannian sum. We already know that the Quadrature rule converge for Riemann integrable functions but I dont want to use that. How can I show that the sum $Q_n(f)=\sum^n_{k=1} w_kf(x_k)$ is a Riemannian sum?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what you exactly want. We call $\sum_{k}^{n} g(x_k)(x_{k}-x_{k-1})$ a Riemann sum of $g$ for a partition $\pi_n$ of the intervall $[a,b]$. Hence rewrite your sum into the above form. So you just choose sutitable $g$ and partition $\pi_n$